# Does fgets change the file descriptor set?

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

So, I can use `FD_ZERO`, `FD_SET` and `FD_ISSET` to mess around with the file descriptor set. The `select()` function may now be used to observe if a certain file object becomes readable (hope my wording is right here). What I want to do is: Read in a sequence of characters from stdin and then send this sequence to a server. I leave out some error messages of the socket stuff here, however, because my question is about `FD_ISSET`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet.in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    static char buffer[256];
    int sock_fd, length, port;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    fd_set input_fdset

    sock_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));


    while (1)
    {
    FD_ZERO(&input_fdset); 
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_fdset);
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &input_fdset); 
    if (select(sock_fd+1, &input_fdset, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) 
        perror("some error");
    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_fdset))
    {
     if(fgets(buffer, 256, stdin) == NULL)  
        {
         printf("connect: Closing socket.");
         break;
        }
     length = strlen(buffer);
     send(sock_fd, buffer, length, 0);
    }
    else
    { 
     length = recv(sock_fd, buffer, 256, 0);
     if(length == 0)
     {
      printf( "Connection closed by remote host.");
      break;
     }
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, length);
     }
     }
       close(sock_fd);
       return(0);
}
```

You can probably guess I came across this code. 
I have troubles to understand the following: Within the while-loop, I add both the socket object and stdin to the file descriptor set. In the next step `select` checks whether there is anything to read from either of these two objects. Then the `if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_fdset))` should ALWAYS be executed, right? I mean the condition is always fulfilled, because we set the `STDIN_FILENO` using `FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_fdset)`. Now, I am within this if-statement. `fgets` reads in my terminal input line by line. When I end this input with ENTER, a newline-character is appended to my buffer and reading from stdin stops. But only until the while-loop is executed again, right? Because in that case `fgets` gets called again as well. Btw I think it is kind of weird to have `fgets` only within this if-statement. Shouldn't it be called before? How can `fgets` become NULL? Only if EOF is reached without reading in any character. This won't happen though, will it? I cannot reach EOF when I am reading from stdin. I think. And now the last question: When would I execute the else-block? For this to happen, the previous if-statement would need to fail. But as I said, `if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &input_fdset)` will never fail.

Ofc I realize I am missunderstanding this code. 
Can somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: All `select` will tell you is that the descriptors in the read-set (after successful return) will not block if you attempt to read from it. Calling any function to read from or set or change any state on the descriptor will not change its status in the set, not until you have called `select` again.

Comment: The code only monitors one fd in the `select` and there is no timeout set. So the only way the `else` block can be reached is if `select` fails. That is, it has nothing to do with `fgets`. But reading into your question a bit: `fgets` doesn't change the fd set directly. It consumes the input which will affect the next `select` calls behaviour and thus what the resulting fd set might be.

Comment: Using `select()` on `STDIN_FILENO` is not going to give reliable information on whether or not calls to `FILE *`-based functions such as `fgets()` or `scanf()` on `stdin` will block or not.  `fgets()`, for example, will block until it gets a full line or `EOF` - `select()` can't detect if there's a full line available.  Nor will `select()` tell if there's already data buffered in the `stdin` stream that has already been read, leading to your code waiting for data that's already been read from the input.

Comment: @kaylum: so are you saying: when my input to stdin ends with ENTER, reading stops and a terminating null is appended to the read in string. And this will now affect the next `select` call. But how will this effect the `select` call? You know what, I actually forgot to mentio the `while (1)`. See my updates

Comment: allright guys, I added the socket stuff, because I realize I have troubles understanding this. Hope the question makes sense.

Comment: nit (which perhaps enlightens a fundamental misunderstanding) It is not correct that "When I end this input with ENTER, a newline-character is appended to my buffer and reading from stdin stops".  The newline is not really appended; it is a piece of data which was read.

Comment: "I cannot reach EOF when I am reading from stdin".  Sure you can.  When you are entering data from a keyboard, type ctrl-d

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for select (`man select`):

"On return, select() replaces the given descriptor sets with subsets consisting of those descriptors that are ready for the requested operation."

The purpose of FD_ISSET is to determine which sets are ready to be read.  The set is changed by the `select` call, by design.

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. But since we have declared both stdin and sock_fd as ready to read by using `FD_SET` , both are ready to read. ...This is probably wrong, but this is how I understand us using `FD_SET`

Comment: No, you did not declare them both as ready to read.  You set them to tell select to examine them.  select determines which are ready to read and modifies the set accordingly.  The value that the set had before you called select is not the value it has when select returns.

Comment: ok, I see. So assume the following: I type in "Hello World" in my terminal. `select` realizes there is sth written on stdin, so stdin becomes ready to read. Now, `if (FD_ISSET())` is executed. I send the msg. In the next execution of the while-loop, there is nothing more from stdin, so the else-block is executed. The msg. is printed on stdout. In the next execution of the while-loop there is still nothing froms tdin. The buffer is now empty, so the socket is closed. This probably leads to `if (fgets(buffer, 256, stdin) == NULL) being executed. Although I still don't get why fgets returns NULL